# Javascript regex multiple decimals

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal

I want to create a regex that only allows 2 decimals or 4 decimals not 1 or 3 or more than 4.

For example:
I want the decimals:

`xx,xx` or `xx,xxxx`

But not: `xx,x` or `xx,xxx` or `xx,xxxxx`

My regex code:

```
^[0-9]*[,.][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}[ ][€$£]$
```

This seems not to be working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try `^[1-9][0-9]*,(?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})$` [here](https://regex101.com/r/3VM2tC/1/).

Comment: It works perfectly, I tried this before with the wrong symbol. I used [] instead of (), thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@UnbearableLightness solution with currency signs and including dots:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*[,.](?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}) [\€\$\£]$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3VM2tC/4)

Comment: The numbers 0.12 or 0.1234 will not be matched though.

Comment: @cars10m OP wants `xx,xx` or `xx,xxxx`.

Comment: If that was the case, `^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)[,.](?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}) [€$£]$` could be used.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

```
^[0-9]*[,.]([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})[ ][€$£]$
```

and if you only need a space between the number and sign, you do not need to put brackets:

```
^[0-9]*[,.]([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}) [€$£]$
```

Comment: This matches `00,00`. Also you don't need the groups to be capturing in this scenario.

Comment: I tried. But if I remove the group, I think it will confuse which part the or sign applies to.